# How do I customize equation numbering in IEEEtrantools?

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering

I'm new to LaTeX. I'm using `IEEEeqnarray`to align equations in my document (a compilation of solved problems), and I'd like to change equation numbering to `(x,y)` where `x` is the question number and `y` is the equation number (which resets with each question). Also I'd be using this within an `enumerate` environment, so I'd like the question number `x` to always match the `item` number.

If possible, please edit the sample below to make it work as described. I included the packages I'm using in my document to ensure compatibility. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools,nccmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

This is a test file for custom equation numbering.
\begin{enumerate}
\item The equations below should be labeled (1.1), unlabeled, and labeled (1.2), in order from top to bottom.
    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
        1+1 & = & 2 \\
        1+2 & = & 3 \nonumber \\
        2+3 & = & 5
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}
\item The equations below should be labeled (2.1), unlabeled, and labeled (2.2), in order from top to bottom.
    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
        3+5  & = & 8 \\
        5+8  & = & 13 \nonumber \\
        8+13 & = & 21
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! How should the equations be numbered outside of an ``enumerate`` environment?

Comment: @Vincent Thank you! I'm using an `enumerate` environment that covers my entire document, so there won't be any equations outside it that need to be numbered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command `\numberwithin` from `amsmath`. This command takes two arguments, both supposed to be counters. Using `\numberwithin{<counter1>}{<counter2>}` will reset `<counter1>` every time `<counter2>` is increased. It will also redefine how a number from `<counter1>` is displayed, representing it in the form "*x*.*y*", where *x* is the current `<counter2>` value, and *y* is the current `<counter1>` value.

The following example should work for your specific case.

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools,nccmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\numberwithin{equation}{enumi}

\begin{document}

This is a test file for custom equation numbering.
\begin{enumerate}
\item The equations below should be labeled (1.1), unlabeled, and labeled (1.2), in order from top to bottom.
    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
        1+1 & = & 2 \\
        1+2 & = & 3 \nonumber \\
        2+3 & = & 5
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}
\item The equations below should be labeled (2.1), unlabeled, and labeled (2.2), in order from top to bottom.
    \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}
        3+5  & = & 8 \\
        5+8  & = & 13 \nonumber \\
        8+13 & = & 21
    \end{IEEEeqnarray}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this will work, but what are the parameters of `\numberwithin`? Just in case I need to change something in the future

Comment: @FrancisGerardMagtibay I added some details in my answer, let me know if it's clearer now.

Comment: @FrancisGerardMagtibay No problem! :) To get used to the mechanics of the site, you could visit the help center, for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).